# Unable to locate element org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":""}

Tags: selenium, testng

I have this test and when I run it works fine until there is this method that store all the values in the excel sheet but I only receive this message after the run.

Here is the method:

```
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    logger.log(LogStatus.INFO,"Storing ticket information");
    reportSubmittedPage.storeDetailstoExcel();
    logger.log(LogStatus.PASS,"Storing ticket information has been done");
```

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to
>   locate element: {"method":"id","selector":""} (Session info:
>   chrome=81.0.4044.138) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161
>   (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),....... version:
>   81.0.4044.138, webStorageEnabled: true} Session ID: db363de6d8159700e9b9bda95379df98 *** Element info: {Using=id, value=}

I already put a thread.sleep before the function.

Comment: update questing with HTML and code trial by you. Thanks